# Assigning string array contents based on an if statement condition

Tags: php

I need to store different table markup code in a php array, as a string. Some of the code that needs to be stored in an array needs to be tested using an if-statement. Before I knew I needed some of the code needs to be tested in such a way, everything was working flawlessly, but now that I know that the string stored is based on an 'if-statement' I am not sure how to code it. Because I need to end the markup for the **current** slot in order to insert the php conditional statement. As a result, I am unable to continue storing data in the 'current' slot, which is what I need.

I have been trying to find work arounds for over an hour now, I appreciate any help with this.

```
$favorites[] = '
        <tr>
          <td><a href="#">'.$files_row['name'].'</a></td>
          <td><a href="#"><img class="table-button" src="images/smallglobe.png"></a></td>
          <td>
            <img src="images/e-mail-icon.PNG">';
                if(strcmp($_files_row['email'],'none') != 0){
                    $favorites[] = '<div style="display:none;"><a href="#" >'.$files_row['email'].'</a></div>';
                }
$favorites[]='        
         </td>
          <td class="table-button-cell">
            <img class="table-button" src="images/eicon.png">
            <div class="phonepopup" style="display:none;">Call: '.$files_row['phone'].'</div>
          </td>
          <td class="table-button-cell"> .... etc....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use a temporary variable for the current slot and assign it to the array, after the if-statements have been evaluated. so you can concatenate the necessary strings:

```
$temp_var = '
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#">'.$files_row['name'].'</a></td>
      <td><a href="#"><img class="table-button" src="images/smallglobe.png"></a></td>
      <td>
        <img src="images/e-mail-icon.PNG">';
            if(strcmp($_files_row['email'],'none') != 0){
                $temp_var .= '<div style="display:none;"><a href="#" >'.$files_row['email'].'</a></div>';
            }
$temp_var .='        
     </td>
      <td class="table-button-cell">
        <img class="table-button" src="images/eicon.png">
        <div class="phonepopup" style="display:none;">Call: '.$files_row['phone'].'</div>
      </td>
      <td class="table-button-cell"> .... etc....';

$favorites[] = $temp_var;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate text or instructions inline:

```
$favorites[5] = 'I prefer '.($age > 18 ? : 'natural' : 'chocolate').' milk';
```

The `(condition?true:false)` syntax does miracles ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

Option one: Append the string using concatenation.

```
  $favorites[index] = '
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">'.$files_row['name'].'</a></td>
        <td><a href="#"><img class="table-button" src="images/smallglobe.png"></a></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/e-mail-icon.PNG">';
    if(strcmp($_files_row['email'],'none') != 0){
        $favorites[index] .= '<div style="display:none;"><a href="#" >'.$files_row['email'].'</a></div>';
    }
    $favorites[index] .= '        
         </td>
         <td class="table-button-cell">
             <img class="table-button" src="images/eicon.png">
             <div class="phonepopup" style="display:none;">Call: '.$files_row['phone'].'</div>
         </td>
         <td class="table-button-cell"> .... etc....

Option 2: Use PHP's ternary operator to do the conditional code inline.

    $favorites[index] = '
        <tr>
          <td><a href="#">'.$files_row['name'].'</a></td>
          <td><a href="#"><img class="table-button" src="images/smallglobe.png"></a></td>
          <td>
            <img src="images/e-mail-icon.PNG">' . ((strcmp($_files_row['email'],'none') != 0) ? '<div style="display:none;"><a href="#" >'.$files_row['email'].'</a></div>' : '') . '        
         </td>
          <td class="table-button-cell">
            <img class="table-button" src="images/eicon.png">
            <div class="phonepopup" style="display:none;">Call: '.$files_row['phone'].'</div>
          </td>
          <td class="table-button-cell"> .... etc....
```

Comment: Well, I cant seem to fix the formatting, but you should be able to understand the gist of what I'm saying...